# Recycler View not opening within a Relative Layout. No compilation errors

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which is using a Relative layout. Within that XML, I have two views - a TextView and a RecyclerView

There are no compilation errors, but the cards from the RecyclerView don't show up while running the app:

Here's the Fragment code:

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TopFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false);
        RecyclerView pizzaRecycler = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.pizza_recycler);
        String[] pizzaNames = new String[2];
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            pizzaNames[i]=Pizza.pizzas[i].getName();
        }
        int[] pizzaImages = new int[2];
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            pizzaImages[i]=Pizza.pizzas[i].getImageResourceId();
        }
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        pizzaRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        CaptionedImagesAdapter adapter = new CaptionedImagesAdapter(pizzaNames, pizzaImages);
        pizzaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setListener(new CaptionedImagesAdapter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PizzaDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PizzaDetailActivity.EXTRA_PIZZANO, position);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return layout;
    }


}
```

Here is the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title_top"
    android:id="@+id/top_text"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pizza_recycler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

And here is the Adapter code:

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CaptionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] captions;
    private int[] imageIds;
    private Listener listener;

    public CaptionedImagesAdapter(String[] captions, int[] imageIds){
        this.captions = captions;
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(CardView v){
            super(v);
            cardView=v;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_captioned_image, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setContentDescription(captions[position]);
        TextView textView = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        textView.setText(captions[position]);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(listener!=null){
                    listener.onClick(position);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return captions.length;
    }

    public static interface Listener{
        public void onClick(int position);
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextView's height in your layout is set to "match_parent". The fragment is set to match_parent as well and since probably the activity is set the same way, this means that your TextView will occupy the whole screen.

I imported your code and with minimal changes to by-pass missing objects, I was able to reproduce the problem.

By changing the height for the TextView to be "wrap_content", you'll be making room for the RecyclerView.